# How to calculate vat using Checkbox after I get total_sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to sum my input by using jQuery. It display correctly

```
$(document).on("change", "#price", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[id *= 'price']").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });

    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

but I want to add some function If I click checkbox How can I calculate vat
and If I type in `<input type="number" name="discount">` How can I discount from total

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" class="form-control" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" class="form-control" value="20" />
<input type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

Here are my function I want to add

1 ) checkbox calculate vat 7%

2 ) textbox calculate discount ex. type 20 , total = - 20

3 ) textbox calculate discount in percent

```
<input id="vat" type="checkbox"  value="7" name="vat" class="vat">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="discount"> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="discount_percent">
```

**update here is my new JavaScript**

I try to  make a variable a for making a calculation in to total sum but I get wrong output  for example I've sum = 100 and I type 50 % discount It should display 50 but dont know why it display 75

```
<script>
  var total = $('.total'),
  discount = $('#discount'),
  percentage = $('#discount_percent')
  var perct = percentage.val();
  a = total.val() * (perct) / 100;


function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("input[id *= 'price']").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });

   total.val((sum - (discount.val())-a).toFixed(2));
}
calculate();


$(document).ready(function () {
  percentage.keyup(function () {
        var perct = percentage.val();
         a = total.val() * (perct) / 100;
         console.log(a);
         calculate();
     });
 });



$(document).on("change keyup", "input", function() {
  if ($('#vat').prop('checked')) {
    discount.val(total.val() * 0.07);
  }else {
    discount.val('');
  }
  calculate();

  $(document).on("change keyup", "input", function() {
      calculate();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version of the solution. You may need to do some unit testing and do the corrections, but it works from what I can see, please check it out and let me know if there is something you are having trouble implementing.

**Summary:**

1. Moved the calculate function outside the events and added the discount calculation logic to it.
2. Since you are using checkbox it will be best to watch for two events namely `change`(for checkbox) and `keyup`(for input box)
3. I added an logic for populating the discount inputs when the checkbox is toggled, its above the place where the calculate function is called!

```js
var total = $('.total'),
  discount = $('#discount'),
  percentage = $('#discount_percent')

function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("input.price").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  
  if ($('#vat').prop('checked')) {
    discount.attr('disabled', false);
    percentage.attr('disabled', false);
    //keep the below three line if you want to keep default value when there is no value present. This needs to be tweaked!
    //if(!percentage.val()){
    //  percentage.val('7');
    //};
    var perct = percentage.val() || 0;
    //to fixed is used to round to 2 decimal places here
    discount.val((parseFloat(total.val()) * (parseFloat(perct) / 100)).toFixed(2));
  } else {
    discount.attr('disabled', true);
    percentage.attr('disabled', true);
    discount.val('');
    percentage.val('');
  }
  
  total.val((sum - (discount.val())).toFixed(2));
}

calculate();
$(document).on("change keyup", "input", function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="">Items</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" class="form-control" value="10" />
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" class="form-control" value="20" />
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="">Vat</label>
  <input id="vat" type="checkbox" value="7" name="vat" class="vat">
  <label for="">Discount Value</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount">
  <label for="">Discount %</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount_percent">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="">Total</label>
  <input type="text" class="total" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: it's work but in percentage , discount  If I want to add my own number for example i check vat total = 27.9 if i want to discount value 20. total should be 7.9 and if I add mre Discount in % it will discount more I think may be I shoud make more 2 function about discount right using on change function

Comment: NO two dom element can have same id

Comment: @NarenMurali Sir i try to play around with It and make new thing but my output getting wrong data lol i dnt knw why  I already update my code if you dnt mind can you advice me pls .

Comment: @user8663822 What test case is failing?

Comment: your code is correctly but i change something using same formula but output not same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156769/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-user8663822).